# Image won't resize properly in Chrome (fiddle)

Tags: css, google-chrome

This fiddle works on firefox but not on chrome. This image is not keeping the aspect ratio:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbBRu/2/)

```
<body style="height:100%;margin:0">
<div id="dvMain" style="width:100%;height:200px;border:1px dashed gray;text-align:center">
    <img id="imgMain "   src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-987-804-9.jpg" style="display:inline-block;height:auto !important;width:auto;max-height:100%  " />
</div>

<span onclick="rez();">Click me</span>
```

```
function rez(){
    $("#dvMain").css("height",  "50px");
}
```

But if i go to inspector and refresh the height property (uncheck/check) it works...

Comment: it seems to work for me on Chrome 26...

Comment: If you use jQuery, you can use the `click` event. By the way, it also works on chrome 28. Do you mean that the image does not keep its ratio ?

Comment: Yes, it is not working in chrome 28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didn't work for me either (on Chrome 28) but changing the code to

```
<body style="height:100%;margin:0">
    <div id="dvMain" style="width:100%;height:200px;border:1px dashed gray;text-align:center">
        <img id="imgMain" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-987-804-9.jpg" 
             style="display:block;height:auto !important;width:auto;max-height:100%;margin: 0 auto;" />
    </div>

    <span onclick="rez();">Click me</span>
</body>
```

and it keeps the aspect ratio.

On the image CSS I changed the `display: inline-block` to `display: block` and added `margin: 0 auto` to centre align the image

Comment: You should precise that you changed `inline-block` to `block`. It's not obvious.

Comment: sorry, thought you'd be able to see the changes in your code more easily than others, will update

Comment: It's not mine, and this is public. It could help other people :)

Comment: Thanks. Is that a bug or is it supposed to work like that? In other browsers it works with inline-block...

Comment: possibly a bug (but not a terrible one) as it worked for people on Chrome 26

Answer (score 1):

Below code works fine too...

```
<body style="height:100%;margin:0">
    <div id="dvMain" style="width:100%;border:1px dashed gray;text-align:center">
        <img id="imgMain" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-987-804-9.jpg" style="height:150px; display:inline-block;" />
    </div>

    <span onclick="rez();">Click me</span>
</body>

function rez(){
  $("img").animate({
      height:'50px'
  })

}
```